# how to add an action to the button that i have on a layout showing as dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, action

how to add action to the button that i have on the Vs_facebook_mode. On abutton click am showing the below dialog box which has two buttons and i want to add some action on the click of those buttons. help me please !

```
mdialog.setContentView(R.layout.vs_facebook_mode);
mdialog.setTitle( " CREATE A GAME " );
mdialog.setCancelable(true);
```

Comment: Are you using AlertDialog or DialogFragment? Could you provide more info?

Answer (score 0):

use layout inflaor to fetch the button from the xml view and add clicklistener like this. u have to do some thing like that

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filename, null);
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonid);

 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
  @Overrid
   public void Click(View view)
{
 //do action here
}
});
```

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
mDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
            mDialog.setTitle( " CREATE A GAME " );
            mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.vs_facebook_mode);
                            mDialog.setCancelable(true);
            Button mButton = (Button) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.button);
            mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    Log.v("The button is clicked.");
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

If you're using DialogFragment or AlertDialog, try [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)